# Permission on SymLink in web server

Tags: php, linux, permissions, webserver, symlink

A little new to PHP, symbolic links, and web servers so I am testing a few things out.

I have a web server in `/volume1/web/` and I am trying to make it accessible only if the user is successfully logged in on the site. Basically, I don't want to be able to just type in the address and have another page or image load.

The symbolic link lies in `/volume1/web/media/` and it points to `/volume1/media/`. Is there anyway to make it so users aren't able to just type in the address `http://ip.of.web.server/media/image.jpg`?

I have a login form at `http://ip.of.web.server/index.php` and the users are stored in a database, but I am still new to this and I'm not sure how to relate that to OS permissions and such. I have an FTP set up on the server as well and I have different users on there. Would there be a way to just use that info for the web page login as well as the symlink permissions? Any info will help, thanks!

For information, I am running a Linux version 3.10.77.

Comment: Which web server (software)?

Comment: Apache HTTP Server 2.2

Comment: You could use apache with mod_authn_dbd: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html

Comment: I apologize, but this is a bit foreign to me. It seems you specify a directory and give it some authorization permissions here, correct? Will this block the example I gave above? It also seems that there are some requirements needed as well?

Comment: Which ftp server (software) are you using?

Comment: FTP softwar is LFTP